# MySql Join 3 tables to find the sum of total (total paid per invoice) in 3rd (receipts) table for each invoice number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables Invoice, Invoice Items, Receipts and invoice receipts tables as below.

[image]

the invoice_receipt works as a junction table between invn_invoice and payment_receipt_master tables. I want to find out how much each invoice has been paid for by summing up invoice_receipt_master.amount_paid.

with the following query i have been able to get the total of the invoices:

```
    select invn.id AS invoice_id, invn.invoice_date AS invoice_date,
sum(invnitms.sub_total) AS total
from invn_invoice invn 
right join invn_invoice_items invnitms on(invnitms.invoice_id = invn.id)
group by invn.id
```

But my problem is I cannot sum up the receipts paid for each invoice. I need a another column next to total as amount paid with receipts total per invoice.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both invoice items and payment receipts have a 1:n relationship with invoices, you cannot do the summing of the two tables in a single query. The records would get duplicated, therefore the calculated sums would be higher. You have to do one one of the summing in a subquery to get a single record by an invoice:

```
select invn.id AS invoice_id, invn.invoice_date AS invoice_date,
sum(invnitms.sub_total) AS total, coalesce(t.sum_paid, 0)
from invn_invoice invn 
left join invn_invoice_items invnitms on(invnitms.invoice_id = invn.id)
left join (select invoice_master_id, sum(amount_paid) as sum_paid
           from invoice_receipt ir
           inner join payment_receipt_master prm on ir.receipt_master_id=prm.id
           group by ir.invoice_master_id) t on t.invoice_master_id=invn.id
group by invn.id, invn.invoice_date, t.sum_paid
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT invn.id, SUM(receipt.amount_paid)
FROM invn_invoice invn JOIN invoice_receipt ir ON invn.id = ir.invoice_master_id
JOIN payment_receipt_master receipt ON ir.receipt_master_id = receipt.id
GROUP BY invn.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

hope this answer your problem

```
    with ctereceipt
as
(
    select ir.invoice_master_id,SUM(prm.amount_paid) amount_paid from invoice_receipt ir
    inner join payment_receipt_master prm on prm.id=ir.receipt_master_id
    group by ir.invoice_master_id 
)
select invn.id AS invoice_id, invn.invoice_date AS invoice_date, 
sum(invnitms.sub_total) AS total,sum(ctr.amount_paid) as amountpaid
 from invn_invoice
 invn inner join invn_invoice_items invnitms on invnitms.invoice_id = invn.id
 inner join ctereceipt ctr on ctr.invoice_master_id=invn.id    
 group by invn.id,invn.invoice_date
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but your query is giving the following result for invoice 22
'22', '2017-01-21', '84000', '18000'
which is wrong as invoice has only one receipt with the amount of 3000

Comment: Only mysql 8.0, which is a development version, supports cte